# Footer is loading before the content loads

Tags: angular, angular6

In my app footer is getting loaded before the events loads. These are the codes I have tried. I have a variable loaded set to false at beginning and later when the event data is loaded from api I set it back to true.

Now in my footer component I set ngIf to check.

If I have *ngIf="loaded" then footer is not shown and if *ngIf="!loaded" footer loads before the event.

Can anybody help me fix this issue?

### events.component.ts

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

    events = [];
    loaded = false;
    constructor(private _eventService: EventService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.events = res;
                    this.loaded = true;
                    console.log(this.loaded);
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

### footer.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="loaded">
```

Comment: try `ngAfterViewInit()` lify cycle hooks to load footer after events load

Comment: @diEcho What to do after using ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: write your logic for displaying footer inside `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: Set `ngAfterViewInit(){
this.loaded = true;} ` instead in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: I am not sure but footer still load before the content. Can help?